# Push Notification not working in Sandbox mode

Tags: iphone, push, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In our organization we are trying to get familiar with push notifications.Our administrator generated a SSL certificate and an app id which one of my colleagues used for developing an app having push notifications which was working nicely.After that administrator disabled the certificate which stopped push notifications working.Now I am working on the same and for that purpose the certificate is enabled again.But When I used it on my machine in a sample app it didn't work.More strangely I ran the app which was on my colleague's machine and it also doesn't receive any notifications now!!!I tried to replace old certificate by the re-enabled one but that also doesn't do the job.What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by disabled the certificate ? Revoked ?

Comment: Yes,he just revoked it.Sorry for wrong wordings:(

Answer (score 1):

If you revoke a certificate, and recreate it, you must download the new certificate because it's not the same certificate, the old  has expired.

Comment: oh!that means I must download it on my machine?But my console gives no such error also.

Comment: You should install the certification on the machine which send notifications.

Comment: I installed the certificate but it didn't work.I am using 'PushMeBaby' app for server side.Can issues be there?Or with port numbers mentioned in it?I am not getting what the issue is...It doesn't even ask about accessing the key which it should ask and doesn't fire an error even if I removed the certificate file from my project.

Comment: I have been trying the code from Ray Wenderlich' tutorial website (part 1 example). 

That works perfectly fine for iphone 4 (ios 5) but it is not working for iPad (ios 4.3.3) and iPhone 4S (ios 5.1). I am trying this in sandbox of course.

Did anyone encounter similar problem. I can not understand why is it not working.

Thanks in advance.